# Creating multiple pages in one request

Tags: next.js, notion-api

I need to create a page for every single day in my database in notion, So can I create pages for each month in one request using notion-api?

Answer (score 3):

No, only a single page can be created per request.

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple requests to create multiple pages.

However, you can make them in parallel using `Promise.all`:

```
import { range } from "lodash-es";
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client";

const notion = new Client();

await Promise.all(
  range(1, 31).map((day) =>
    notion.pages.create({
      parent: {
        database_id: "...",
      },
      properties: {
        day,
      },
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: Well, you'll probably hit the requests limit, according to the Notion documentation: 

"The rate limit for incoming requests is an average of 3 requests per second."